# PhotoChooserTask built in crop option for windows phone 8.1

Tags: windows-phone-8.1

In Windows Phone 8 I was using PhotoChooserTask to get images from phone gallery and when I fixed Pixel width and height automatically windows phone start a page for cropping the selected image. Can someone tell me how to enable this option with FileOpenPicker?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately the Windows phone 8.1 SDK does not have this operation, and I swear I tried look for it in every where, and the people of MDSN tell me it is impossible.... But you can try two options:

First: In the workflow of FileOpenPicker the user has two options take a image file already exists or take a new picture like the follow pic:

[image: Windows Phone 8.1 SDK]

So in this case you do nothing and talk to UX area that is impossible to do =) .

Second: You can create a module(separated project) in the same Project Solution which uses the Windows Phone 8.0 SDK (instead 8.1). Do what you need to get the job done using the PhotoChooserTask... After in the main project add a reference to it and be happy.

Some big projects are using this solution because the 8.1 SDK removed a lot of features of 8.0 SDK and did some things hard to do.

One project you should take a look in the source code is https://telegram.org/apps

I hope it helps.

Good Luck!