# Built-in Windows Phone 8.1 Image Crop Screen

Tags: image, windows-phone-8.1, crop, lumia-imaging-sdk

I'm developing an app using Windows Phone 8.1 where I'm loading an image from the PictureLibrary into a BitmapImage and displaying it in a 150 pixels square.

What I need is to be able to, after selecting an image, open a control where the user can select an area to crop the image to a 150 pixels square, similar to [this](http://wscont1.apps.microsoft.com/winstore/1x/fa72bbb0-5d25-4485-a23f-b578dd2d29b8/Screenshot.243081.1000001.jpg).

Were I using Windows Phone 8, I would be able to achieve this using PhotoChooserTask, as pointed out in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25769364/photochoosertask-built-in-crop-option-for-windows-phone-8-1).

The beta version of Lumia Imaging SDK had the EditingSession, as shown [here](http://www.microsofttranslator.com/bv.aspx?from=es&to=en&a=http://geeks.ms/blogs/jyeray/archive/2013/07/21/windows-phone-8-nokia-imaging-sdk-2-editando-im-225-genes.aspx), but it was only available when the SDK was in beta, as answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20174638/nokia-imaging-sdk-problems-with-editingsession-class).

It seems there's no built-in Windows Phone 8.1 control to do this, nor an easy way to do so.

Answer (score 1):

I am not aware of a UI control to do this for you. To crop an image using the Lumia Imaging SDK add a cropFilter to a FilterEffect and render it. Starting with a source, I will assume that you will have a StorageFile, so a StorageFileImageSource will be perfect for you.

```
StorageFile sourceFile = ...
using (var source = new StorageFileImageSource(sourceFile))
using (var filterEffect = new FilterEffect(source))
using (var renderer = new JpegRenderer(filterEffect))
{
   filterEffect.Filters = new [] { new CropFilter(x, y, 150, 150));

   var result = await renderer.RenderAsync();
}
```

To familiarize yourself with the Lumia Imaging SDK I suggest starting with the [Core Concepts documentation page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn859580.aspx)

Comment: I was planning on using the Lumia's SDK CropFilter to crop it, but unfortunately there's no control on it. Therefore, I'm trying to develop a control where I can select the area and apply it'sw coordinates on the CropFilter.

Comment: Yes, you will have to make the selection control yourself - Lumia Imaging SDK doesn't provide any UI controls.